# Find how many duplicate array elements

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

This is the array and code

```
 $array = array(1, 3, 3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 14); 
 $c = array_count_values($array);
 print_r($c);
```

I get an output like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [7] => 1
    [9] => 4
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 1
    [14] => 1
)
```

I want to get the number of values which are more than or equal to 2, which is `([3],[9],[11])`:

```
Duplicate groups: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the number of values which are >2 ([3],[9],[11]):

You mean more or equal to 2. Which in this case leads us to `>=`:

```
$array = array(1, 3, 3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 14);
$c = array_count_values($array);

$r = array();
foreach($c as $k => $v) {
    if($v >= 2) {
        $r[$k] = $v;
    }
}

print "Duplicate groups: " . count($r);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `array_filter` function to filter out the duplicates:

```
$array = array(1, 3, 3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 14); 
$c = array_count_values($array);
$c = array_filter($c, function($v){return $v > 1;});
$c = count($c);

echo "Duplicate groups: $c";
```

Comment: Nicer solution than the accepted answer. Way to go!

Answer (score 1):

An Improved version:

```
$array = array(1, 3, 3, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12, 14); 
$array1 = array_count_values($array);
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
  if($value > 1){
    $array2[$key] = $value;
  }
}
print "Duplicate groups: ".count($array2);
```